# Why PhpStorm shows highlight error for Laravel echo syntax

Tags: javascript, laravel, phpstorm

I written a Laravel `echo` code in PhpStorm like this:

```
echo.private('user-channel.5').listen('.NewMessage', (e) => {
    alert('salam');
    console.log(e);
});
```

But PhpStorm highlights a part of that code as an error.

This is an screenshot of what is happened:

[image]

Also when I use `Ctrl+Alt+L` to formatting, PhpStorm does not format this lines of code properly.

Of course when I run `gulp` command to compile file contain `Echo` codes, that runs without problem.

Which settings should be change to solve this problem in PhpStorm ?

Comment: 1) This is JavaScript and not PHP code, right? 2) What JavaScript language version did you set in `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`? It should be set to one that supports such syntax (arrow functions?).

Comment: @LazyOne,1)yes 2)Ecmascript 5.1 , is it right ?

Comment: Well ... (http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) -- it seems to be ES6 so `ECMAScript 5.1` is definitely wrong here -- try `ECMAScript 6` or something even more newer (`Flow` perhaps...)  -- sorry, I'm not a "proper" JavaScript person -- just basic jQuery and alike.